# Pass the value to the database which is equal to the auto increament field value

Tags: mysql

I have a Insert statementt let us say,

```
Insert into tablename(A,B,C,D)vales(2,3,4);
```

Let `A` is an auto increment field.SO there is no necessary to pass the values.

Now i want to pass the value of `D` which is same as value of `A`. But `D` is not an auto increment field. Now how i can pass the values to the database?.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why? You seem to have broken 3NF here.

Comment: There is some condition where in D may not be equal to A, D might be zero in some cases.

Comment: Why dont you use `sequence` here ? I am confused with question...As per your requirement. You can do one thing , insert value into `A` and `D` using sequence n then depending upon your condition update `D` to zero

Comment: There should be no conditions in which D is *equal* to A in 3NF. Sounds like a job for a boolean.

Comment: totally agreed with @EJP. Normalization is must.

Comment: Can we Insert it first and then update it with the `A` value?

Comment: If you specify `A` in the list of columns after the table name you need to provide a value for it. In your example `A` is `2`, `B` is `3`, `C` is `4` and MySQL reports the error "Column count doesn't match value count" because of the missing value for column `D`. You can either don't specify `A` in the list of columns or you put `NULL` as its value in the list of values: `INSERT INTO tablename(A, B, C, D) VALUES (NULL, 2, 3, 4);`

Comment: See, as per your condition is dont think there is need of `D` column in table.
You said data in column `D` can be equal to column `A` or in some condition it's `0`.
So you can do one thing, keep columns in table as `A B C ` suppose you want data of column `D` (which is not in new table structure) insted of `D` pick the data from `A` with condition
`SELECT IF(your condition ,0,A) A from table`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value from `information_schema`

```
INSERT INTO tableName (B,C,D)
SELECT 2, 3, AUTO_INCREMENT
    FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "databaseName"
    AND TABLE_NAME = "tablename";
```